# How to pass input parameters when running Workflow from within Workflow?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

When starting workflow within a workflow we can pass `Input` parameters for the execution of a step function. So far I can pass `Execution Context` object as a parameter but that does not contain the `Input` data of the task that starts new StepFunction, instead it holds data of the parent step functions execution input data.

How can we pass the input data of this task instead of execution context?

```
{
  "Type": "Task", 
  "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::states:startExecution",
  "Parameters": { 
      "Input": {"input.$": "$$.Execution.Input"},
      "StateMachineArn":"arn:aws:states..."
  },
  "End": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this came from a comment on another platform. It is obvious actually. We just need to pass the root json path to input param.

```
{
  "Type": "Task", 
  "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::states:startExecution",
  "Parameters": { 
      "Input": {"input.$": "$"},
      "StateMachineArn":"arn:aws:states..."
  },
  "End": true
}
```